# No provider for ngControl when transcluding an input to an NPM package's wrapper component with ReactiveForms

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components, angular-forms

Sorry for the mouthful of a title. Here's the error that I'm running into:

`MyComponent.html:37 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[NgControl]: 
  StaticInjectorError[NgControl]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgControl!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:993)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10878)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12110)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12608)`

And here's the use-case: I have a library that another team built (we'll call it "third party library" that provides input wrappers. In my component, I have a reactive form and a template structure that looks like this:

```
<form *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">

<div *ngIf="loggedIn">

    <div *ngIf="!this.errorCode">
        <div class="form-account-num-wrapper" *ngIf="!hasCardInfo">

            <div>
                Enter Card Details
            </div>

            <thirdparty-input class="form-label-hover"
                        minlengtherror="Minimum Credit Card Length is 13-digits."
                        maxlengtherror="Maximum Credit Card Length is 19-digits"
                        requirederror="Card Number is required."
                        label="Card Number"
                        [ngClass]="cardClasses"
                        [formGroup]="form"
                        [icons]="icons"
                        (reset)="resetField('cardNumber')">
                <input id="cardNumber"
                       autocomplete="off"
                       thirdpartyInputDirective
                       formControlName="cardNumber"
                       required="true"
                       minlength="16"
                       type="text"/>
            </thirdparty-input>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry that the markup and error message don't exactly match. I trimmed some of the markup to focus on the error, which is being thrown when processing this line here:

`<input id="cardNumber"
    autocomplete="off"
    thirdpartyInputDirective
    formControlName="cardNumber"
    required="true"
    minlength="16"
    type="text"/>`

I feel like I've seen other third-party libraries do something like this before, but I'm not sure what they've done differently. I've looked into ngTemplateOutlet and ngTemplateOutletContext, but wasn't able to find much about them. What I did find made them seem like they weren't a solution to this.

Has anyone seen this issue before? If so, have anyone had any luck solving it? I believe it has to do with the directive, but if I remove that directive, the component starts throwing errors because it expects the transcluded element to have the `thirdPartyInputDirective` attached to it.

Comment: I have seen this issue. Create reproduction and i will try to help you)

Comment: I dont think it's something that I can reproduce in a plunkr. I believe it's caused because the thirdparty library is AOT compiled.